# Why is it that in a buffer solution the equilibrium concentrations may be assumed to be the initial concentrations?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, equilibrium, solutions

Considering the Henderson–Hasselbalch equation,

$$\text{pH} = \text{p}K_a + \lg \frac{[\ce{AcO⁻}]} {[\ce{AcOH}]}$$

$$\text{p}K_a = \lg \frac{[\ce{AcO⁻}][\ce{H⁺}]} {[\ce{AcOH}]}$$

Why are the values for the concentrations often the initial concentration added?

$$\text{pH} = \text{p}K_a + \lg \frac{[\ce{AcO⁻}]_0} {[\ce{AcOH}]_0}$$

Comment: Because concentration shift to reach equilibrium is negligible.

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: Remember this isn't pure math where $\pi$ is known to billions of digits. Equilibrium constants are only known to 2 or 3 significant figures generally. Book problems will in almost all cases require nothing more than a quadratic equation to solve by making the right chemical assumptions. Solving 5 equations with 5 unknowns isn't problematic for a computer but it is miserable when doing so by hand.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/172402